# Storing Fetch data from API locally

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to store fetched data from an API and save into either a local file or into a database. So far I have a fully functioning fetch() method that is capable of displaying data onto a front-end application but I am unsure as to how to do the latter.

The following is my fetch method:

```
    fetch('https://thesession.org/events/new?format=json&perpage=50')
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(events => {
                this.setState({
                  newEvents: events.events
                });
              });
```

Comment: You could store it in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: You might be looking for redux, which will be best solution for storage and easy flow of data to use

Comment: if you want to store in local you can use redux + redux persist ...